# Why does this let one prime number through?

Tags: python-2.7

I'm going back and tooling around with Project Euler questions to see if I can speed up my code, this is 003: finding the max prime factor of a really big number.

```
def is_prime(n):
    '''check if n is prime'''
    if n == 1: return 0
    elif n == 2: return 1
    elif n % 2 == 0: return 0

    for i in range(3, int(n**0.5) +1, 2):
        if n % i == 0:
            return 0
    else:
        return 1

factor_list = []
the_number = 600851475143
for i in range(3, int(the_number**0.5) +1, 2):
    if the_number % i == 0: factor_list.append(i)

print factor_list
for i in factor_list:
    if is_prime(i) == False: factor_list.remove(i)

print factor_list
print max(factor_list)
```

The first print call prints: `[71, 839, 1471, 6857, 59569, 104441, 486847]`
So far, so good, printing the pre-n^0.5 factors of n.

The second print call prints: `[71, 839, 1471, 6857, 104441]`
Wait, how did 104441 slip through the is_prime function?

The third print call prints the incorrect answer, namely 104441.  My question is how is 104441 slipping through?

Comment: Why does `is_prime` return `0` or `1` instead of `True` or `False`? And why are you then checking the output against `False`?

Comment: @murgatroid 0 is false, and any non-zero value is true, they are synonymous.  In fact, operations that return a Boolean value return either 0 or 1.  Also, this does not affect whether or not my function is letting 10441 slip through.

Comment: 0 is not False except when coerced to a Boolean. They are not equal. This is not C. And I thought that might be the problem when I first read the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you have an issue with your for loop. When you use a for-each loop, you usually don't want to remove values because it ends up skipping over some. So I think what is happening is that `59569` gets removed, and then because you remove it, your next `i` value is `486847`.

If you want a working solution, refer to steveha's code.

Comment: Thank you, I think that your answer is correct.  I'm not looking for working code, mostly just wanted to find out why my original code wasn't working.  I'm going to do some testing by stepping through smaller, more workable numbers.  I think that will verify your answer.  Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

It's always tricky to try to modify a list while looping over it.  It's better and safer to just build the list you need, rather than trying to pull out values you don't need.

This code works perfectly:

```
factor_list = [n for n in xrange(3, int(the_number**0.5) +1, 2) if the_number % n == 0]
print(factor_list)

prime_factors = [n for n in factor_list if is_prime(n)]
print(prime_factors)

answer = max(prime_factors)
print(answer)
```

Also, you should be returning `False` and `True` from `is_prime()`, not `0` and `1`.

Comment: Excellent advice and good code.  Still can't wrap my head around why is_prime is letting 104441 slip through.  Also is True, False over 1, 0 PEP-8 style or a personal preference, they being synonymous?

Comment: `is_prime()` doesn't let 104441 slip through; my code works fine.  The problem is that your loop to remove values from a list *while looping on the list* didn't work right.  It's a loop issue.  My code just builds the desired list, and `is_prime()` does work, so the result is correct.  As for the `True` and `False` issue, it's not explicitly in PEP 8 but it's just an example of writing code that says what you mean.  You are really evaluating a true/false condition; you even compare with `False` in your code.  Since Python offers built-in `True` and `False`, use them.  This isn't C! :-)

Comment: Sorry, you misunderstood. I was referring to why is was slipping through _my_ code. Your code is efficient and less awkward than what I wrote -with the added benefit that _yours_ works.  Sorry for the confusion.  Also, point taken on True/False and will be applied.  Thanks again.